# Return value of program in cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin

I have a code in C++ like this

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  exit(-1);
}
```

I am on Windows machine, make-ing and running this program in Cygwin. I want to echo return value (for testing purposes).

```
echo $?
```

gives 255 insted of -1, why? (overflow?)

Comment: perhaps because the windows shell uses an unsigned byte for return types, and -1 represented as an unsigned byte is 255

Comment: yeah, sure, but I need to exit with value below 0

Comment: you are exiting with a value below 0.  If the windows shell can't represent it, what good does it do you?  If you're capturing it in the shell and passing it to another program, you can convert from unsigned byte to signed int and you'll have your negative back.

Answer (score 0):

exit takes integers (0-255), `return -1` is different, exit returns 255 when given value out of range

Comment: would be worth testing this; try `exit(-2)` and see if you still get 255 or 254.  254 would indicate that it's a signed to unsigned conversion, 255 would indicate a value out of range.

Comment: Everything is worth testing.

Comment: return does seem to have same behavior as exit in matter of return value in $?

Comment: Why do you need to return negative statuses?

Comment: Well, I do not _need_ to. But I wanted to.